# IDEA: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: java, intellij-idea

My Jetbains IDEA encountered a major error. When I run any project, including a new project, the standard output window show below:

> Buildfile: C:\Users\kent\IdeaProjs\Demo\src\main\java\com\kent\Test.java
>
> BUILD FAILED
>   C:\Users\kent\IdeaProjs\Demo\src\main\java\com\kent\Test.java:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
>
> Total time: 0 seconds
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

And the content of Test.java only is :

```
package com.kent.test;

public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("hihi");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was disabled plugin using File/Settings/Plugins.

The plugin that had been interfered in test execution was Ant Debugger. In your case it may be another plugin for ant.